# Where does the differential come from when passing from a discrete sum to a continuous case, for instance for the case of the inner product?

Tags: calculus, inner-products, intuition, riemann-sum

I'm trying to develop some intuition behind the inner product. I understand for two n-dimensional vectors we can compute the dot product as:

$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i b_i$

So for two discrete functions, their dot product would be:

$(f \cdot g) = \sum_{n} f(n) \cdot g(n)$.

Now say we have two continuous functions $f$ and $g$, where a vector element is given by $\lim_{{dx \to 0}} f(x+(i*dx))$, where $i$ is the element of the vector. The dot product is the result of multiplying the corresponding elements of two vectors and summing these products:

$\lim_{{dx \to 0}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x+(i*dx)) \cdot g(x+(i*dx))$.

Which leads to the inner product:

$(f \cdot g) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \cdot g(x) \, dx$

My question is where did the $dx$ come from?

when integrating the are under the curve of a function $f(x)$, we split up the area into smaller rectangles of base $dx$ and height $f(x)$ so that the area of one of these rectangles is $f(x)dx$. When we take the limit as dx tends to 0 and sum up all of these areas, we get $\lim_{{dx \to 0}} \sum f(x)dx = \int f(x)dx$. Here, the $dx$ comes from $area = base*height$.

In my thought process above, I did not have the need to multiply by $dx$ so I am quite confused as to how it makes its way into the inner product defintion.

I hope I have been clear, this is my first post! Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Please edit if my new title doesn't accurately convey your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you write
$$
\lim_{dx\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f\big( x + i\cdot dx\big)g\big(x + i\cdot dx\big),
$$
you quickly run into the problem that this limit does not exist! Take for instance the constant function $f \equiv 1 \equiv g$. Then, the above becomes $\lim_{dx \to 0} n$ which, if I interpret your $n$ correctly to be something like $1/dx$, diverges. You can construct other examples, where the limit goes to $-\infty$ or does not even diverge to $\pm\infty$, but completely.

Instead, you should rather think of the discrete inner product to be
$$
(f\cdot g) = \sum_n f(n)g(n)\cdot 1,
$$
where the 1 comes from the fact that $dn = (n+1) - n = 1$. In that sense, the definition for the continuous case might be interpreted as the limit
$$
\lim_{dx \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x + i\cdot dx)g(x + i\cdot dx)\cdot dx,
$$
even though I do not like this notation very much ($n$ is not specified, $x$ isn't either, and one should use Lebesgue's integral whenever possible!).